# Ubuntu is gone after reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: installation, boot, bootloader

My Windows 7 got infected with a seriouly bad virus, just because I disabled my anti-virus, so after I re-enabled it I tryed to fight of viruses by doing a start-up scan, but my anti-virus froze and got disabled by the viruse, and all system files also got infected. So I re-installed Windows 7 and now I don't see the Ubuntu boot loader and I don't know what to do. I don't want to have to re-install Ubuntu too.

I'm new to linux, I don't even know what grub is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ubuntu install media to boot and use `fdisk` to check the partition (ID is 83).
Then mount it to `/mnt` and try installing grub to MBR. `grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`.

When it finished without error, reboot the system and you can see grub during start and can enter Ubuntu, but not Win7. After you enter Ubuntu, you can run `sudo update-grub2` to update such as:

```
grub.cfg ...
Found Debian background: moreblue-orbit-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```